# Conflict resolution in Android's SQLiteDatabase with multiple key fields

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in a SQLite database with multiple key fields ("lang" and "name") and I want to replace a fully row when there is a conflict.

I have read in other questions that the easiest way to do this, also compatible with API LEVEL <8, is to use the clause:

```
UNIQUE (id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

on table creation.

But as far as my table uses two columns ("lang" and "name") as primary key, I do not know how to do the same.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick for you:

```
UNIQUE(lang, name) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

Comment: Oh, how obvious. :-D Thanks a lot.